# How to synchronize a Processing script and the Microsoft kinect

Tags: java, processing, average, kinect, frequency

I'm working on this code, which manage data coming from the Microsoft Kinect. The code average the values of some frames, the number of those to average is defined by int numPreviousToConsider. The reason of the average is to make the data smoother and more stable. So I expected to reduce the error increasing the number of frames to mediate. This doesn't happen, the error is reduced considering the average of "a bunch" of frames instead of just one, but considering 40 or 4000 frames the error doesn't change. 
Here the frequencies:
Kinect frequency : 30Hz, so produces 30 frames per second;
Code frequency: 60, defined by frameRate(60) on lines 12;
Finally I save a .txt file every 4 seconds.

I determine the error scanning an unchanging object and comparing the data.

Is there something wrong with the frequencies used or something else?

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import SimpleOpenNI.*;
import java.util.*;
SimpleOpenNI kinect;
List<int[]> previousKinectValues = new LinkedList<int[]>();
int numPreviousToConsider = 120;
void setup()
{
  size(640, 480);
  kinect = new SimpleOpenNI(this);
  kinect.enableDepth();
  frameRate(60);
}
int precedente = millis();
void draw()
{
  kinect.update();
  PImage depthImage = kinect.depthImage();
  image(depthImage, 0, 0);
  int[] newDepthValues = kinect.depthMap();

  previousKinectValues.add(newDepthValues);
  if (previousKinectValues.size() > numPreviousToConsider) {
    previousKinectValues.remove(0);
  }
  int[] depthValues = average(previousKinectValues);
  depthValues = reverse(depthValues);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  Deque<Integer> row = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  int kinectheight = 770; // kinect distance from the baselevel [mm]
  int scaleFactor = 1;
  int pixelsPerRow = 640;
  int pixelsToSkip = 40;
  int rowNum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < depthValues.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i == (rowNum + 1) * pixelsPerRow) {
      fillStringBuilder(sb, row);
      rowNum++;
      sb.append("\n");
      row = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
    if (i >= (rowNum * pixelsPerRow) + pixelsToSkip) {
      row.addFirst((kinectheight - depthValues[i]) * scaleFactor);
    }
  }
  fillStringBuilder(sb, row);
  String kinectDEM = sb.toString();
  final String[] txt= new String[1]; //creates a string array of 2 elements
  int savingtimestep = 2000;  // time step in millisec between each saving
  if (millis() > precedente + savingtimestep) {
    txt[0] = "ncols         600\nnrows         480\nxllcorner     0\nyllcorner     0\ncellsize      91.6667\nNODATA_value  10\n" +kinectDEM;
    saveStrings("kinectDEM0.tmp", txt);
    precedente = millis();
    //  delete the old .txt file, from kinectDEM1 to kinectDEMtrash
    File f = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM1.txt"));
    boolean success = f.delete();

    //  rename the old .txt file, from kinectDEM0 to kinectDEM1
    File oldName1 = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM0.txt"));
    File newName1 = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM1.txt"));
    oldName1.renameTo(newName1);
    //  rename kinectDEM0.tmp file to kinectDEM0.txt
    File oldName2 = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM0.tmp"));
    File newName2 = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM0.txt"));
    oldName2.renameTo(newName2);

  }
}
void fillStringBuilder(StringBuilder sb, Deque<Integer> row) {
  boolean emptyRow = false;
  while (!emptyRow) {
    Integer val = row.pollFirst();
    if (val == null) {
      emptyRow = true;
    } else {
      sb.append(val);
      val = row.peekFirst();
      if (val != null) {
        sb.append(" ");
      }
    }
  }
}
int[] average(List<int[]> previousKinectValues) {
  if (previousKinectValues.size() > 0) {
    int[] first = previousKinectValues.get(0);
    int[] avg = new int[first.length];
    for (int[] prev : previousKinectValues) {
      for (int i = 0; i < prev.length; i++) {
        avg[i] += prev[i];
      }
    }
    int num = previousKinectValues.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < avg.length; i++) {
        avg[i] /= num;
    }
    return avg;
  }
  return new int[0];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Which exact line of code are you talking about? What exactly does it do that's different from what you expect it to do?

Comment: Whats the point in doubling the frequency?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be clear, I would expect that the bigger the number of frames averaged the smaller should be the error. It's like repeating a measure more than one time to get a more realist value. The kinect provide the depth image, in which the value of each pixel is proportional to the distance of the target. So I set the number of frames to average with int numPreviousToConsider = 120; but if I chose here a value rangin from 40 to 4000 or even bigger, the error doesn't decreases. The error appear to be insensitive to this parameter. This is because I'm wondering about the frequencies...

Comment: If the error is evenly distributed and small enough, it shouldn't change much considering 40 or 4000 frames. Try to introduce bigger error, then you should be able to see a difference. But it will still go towards a shared minimum not necessarily a (significantly) smaller error.

Comment: Thanks @Fildor, can you suggest me any reference about this issue?

Comment: Well, apart from calculus? Not from the top of my head but I'll see if I find a good resource. Wikipedia is at least **a** source ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error

Comment: So, you will flatten a possible error "peek" increasing the considered frames, so it will produce a lot smaller amplitude over time compared to the small set of frames. But if you are seeing only a small noise ... well. Then that's what the accuracy of kinect gives you.

Comment: Thanks @Fildor, I focused on the code ignoring the math. I guess, as you said, that's the kinect's accuracy.